# ASP.NET - Call Web Service From User Control ( .Ascx ) Returns Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, internal-server-error

so I have some problem. The Problem's Goal is that, when i try to call Web Service from User Control with Ajax, I got 500 Internal Server Error.

There is my code sample:

Web Service .CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;


[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class BudgetJson : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public BudgetJson () 
    {
    }



    [WebMethod]
    public static String GetRecordJson()
    {
        return " Hello Master, I'm Json Data ";
    }
}
```

User Control ( .Ascx ) File ( Ajax Call )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "BudgetJson.asmx",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) 
                {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });
```

So, when page loads and request is sent, I got such response:

> soap:ReceiverSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was
>   unable to process request. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at
>   the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
>   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage
>   message)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>   Boolean& abortProcessing)    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---

If i will add method name to url, I got such error:

> Unknown web method GetRecordJson. Parameter name: methodName
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method
>   GetRecordJson. Parameter name: methodName

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 2):

A couple things on the server-side:

The method should not be static. That's only the case for "page methods" on ASPX pages.

Second, you need to decorate the service class with the `[ScriptService]` attribute to be able to communicate with it in JSON, which I'm assuming you probably want to do since you're using jQuery.

```
[ScriptService]
public class BudgetJson : System.Web.Services.WebService {
  [WebMethod]
  public String GetRecordJson()
  {
    return " Hello Master, I'm Json Data ";
  }
}
```

On the client-side, you need to specify which method you want to execute in your `$.ajax()` URL:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "BudgetJson.asmx/GetRecordJson",
  data: "{}",
  // The charset and dataType aren't necessary.
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

You can also simplify the `$.ajax()` usage a bit, as shown above. The [charset isn't necessary and jQuery automatically detects the dataType](http://encosia.com/save-yourself-some-typing-when-you-call-asp-net-services/) from the headers sent back from the server.

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili There was a client-side issue I missed originally. Updated my answer.

Comment: Also updated client side script but nothing new, does this code works on your machine ? does there is some configurations problem ? if this code runs on your machine, please share your web.config file...

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili The configuration requirements depend on which version of ASP.NET you're using. Have a look at this: http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/

Comment: This project runs over .net 2.0. my web.config file is also like your sample. Does there is some IIS problem ?

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili You'll need to install the ASP.NET Ajax Extensions on the server to get that working with ASP.NET 2.0 (as mentioned in the post I linked in my last comment; do what it says and it should work).